# Adding a column to a dataframe, whose every element is a list containing a single zero

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[[1,2],[3,2],[5,2]],'b':[[1],[9],[9,9]]})
```

Now,I want to add a column 'c' to this dataframe, whose every element is a list containing a single zero([0]). So that my df would look like,

```
       a     b      c
0   [1, 2]  [1]    [0]
1   [3, 2]  [9]    [0]  
2   [5, 2]  [9, 9] [0]
```

I tried using assign function that looked like,
`df = df.assign(c=[0])` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could assign an appropriately sized list by creating it `len(df)` times:

```py
df.assign(c = [[0]] * len(df))
# or more simply:
df['c'] = [[0]] * len(df)
df
```

Output:

```
        a       b    c
0  [1, 2]     [1]  [0]
1  [3, 2]     [9]  [0]
2  [5, 2]  [9, 9]  [0]
```

Comment: I think `df['c'] = [[0]] * len(df)` will be fine too

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew you are indeed correct, I used `assign` because OP did in their question, but that is indeed simpler. I've added it as an alternative to the answer.